# map many strings to one string in perl

Tags: perl

I want to do something like

```
$val = "value1"
my %test = ("value1" => "yes", "value2" => "yes", "value3" => "yes");
print  $test{$val};
```

So if either $val is equal to either value1, value2 or value3 then display "yes" otherwise  display "no"

Not sure if I'm doing it the correct/efficient way. I'm new to perl

Comment: Really, you should test if the key exists, then test if the value is defined, then test if it's equal to "yes". Yay perl.

Comment: @mkb: assuming that the hash is static and is composed only out of constants, checking whether a value is undefined is unnecessary.

Comment: @mkb You only need to check for exists and defined if a valid value of the key may be 0 or ''.

Comment: I'm just joking; I love perl, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (defined $test{$val}) {
    print "$test{$val}\n";  # or you might use: print "yes\n"; depending on what you're doing
}
else {
    print "no\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to test whether a value with such a key exists in the hash:

```
print exists $tests{$val} ? $tests{$val} : "no";
```

In general, after checking for its existence, you have to check for its definedness via `defined`, but in your particular case this is not necessary since the `%test` hash seems to be constant and is composed only out of constants which do not include `undef`.

Comment: You don't *have* to check if such a value exists. You only have to check if you want to use that particular value.

Answer (score 1):

Is a hash the best possible data structure here when there are only two options? Here are three possible alternative subroutines that will equally satisfy the requirement:

```
sub test_ternary {
    $_[0] eq 'value1' ? 'yes' :
    $_[0] eq 'value2' ? 'yes' :
    $_[0] eq 'value3' ? 'yes' : 'no'  ;
}

sub test_regex { $_[0] =~ /value[123]/ ? 'yes' : 'no' }

use feature 'switch';
sub test_switch {
    given ( $_[0] ) {

        return 'yes' when /value[123]/;

        default { return 'no'; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is tempting to benchmark and micro-optimize the three alternatives ;)

Comment: Don't forget smart match: `print $value~~{"value1","value2","value3"]?"yes":"no"`

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat complicated answers here.

If the **valid** values in your hash can not be zero or empty string (or any other value which evaluates to "false" in perl), you can do:

```
say $test{$val} ? $test{$val} : "no";
```

This expression will be "false" if `$test{$val}` either does not exist, is undefined, is empty, or is zero.

Comment: `say $test{$val} || 'no'` if you are sure valid values in `%test` are always true